# Multiple ways to do things in Magento - Which one is correct? (My example is with Attribute Sets / Groups)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

More of a best practice question as I don't want to start down the wrong path.

The following link from the Magento Wiki shows how to add Attribute sets programmatically: [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/programmatically_adding_attributes_and_attribute_sets).

It also seems you can use the class `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` and access the methods within to add the attributes etc i.e

```
$groupSetup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$groupSetup->addAttributeSet($entityTypeId, $name);
```

In my mind, the second option is quicker and simpler but is there a rule on how this data should be added? i.e Is one option likely to change whereas another isn't?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to do it programmatically rather than in the admin?

Comment: I am writing an integration module between Magento and some software.

Comment: Then don't instantiate `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` by yourself, use a setup script.

Comment: This isn't being done during setup. It's importing data from another system on an ad-hoc basis. From what I have been reading, it's Ok to call this class outside of the installer and with it being more compact and readable it makes more sense to me to use it.